# How to install a third party app automatically with default ones while doing factory reset on android

Tags: android, security, kernel

I want to add a third party android application to the default application list in the android kernel/root files, so that whenever the factory reset process is running, the third party app is automatically installed in the phone with other default applications (like: Gmail, Samsung ChatOn, etc..).

I don't want to recover/reinstall the apps after a factory rest from backup or google play store.

**Explanation, why I need this:** Say, my phone is been hijacked or stolen. But I want to get my phone back. There are so many apps that are for anti-theft. But, If these thief or hijacker is smart enough, then he can wipe all the data and do a factory reset. And then the "anti-theft" app can't do anything without being re-installed. And the Google account (which was associated with my phone) may be changed. Now as far as I know the only way to get back my phone is "IMEI" tracking. And for this I need to go through all police 'hassles'. So, I want to know that is there any way or something that will force android to install the third party app right after/during the factory reset process?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple "dont't remove this at Factory Reset" of the App after "just" a Factory reset just install the App on `/system/app` on your rooted phone. The System Partition and all its Apps doesn't get affected by a Factory Reset. This can't help if your hijacker or thief reflashes the Rom. But in this scenario your only option would be to write a custom and protected Bootloader and this isn't quite as simple.

Comment: If, I root the phone, install the app on `/system/app`, the phone got factory reseted then will the phone still remain rooted?

Comment: Yes of course. Factory Reset is nothing Else than a wipe of the Data and Cache Partition. Rooting your phone is a change on the Kernel side

Comment: Hey dude. After a reset my app will survive but its data will be wiped as well, right? Is there a way to keep it? Or somewhere to keep a file with its settings after that reset? Thanks

Comment: If you want to keep the data, why do a factory reset in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can write your own app which can install the third party one or alternately you can recover that app after factory reset using **AppBrain** or something like that.Check some good solutions from these-

- [Automatic factory reset and app installation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20146/automatic-factory-reset-and-app-installation?lq=1)
- [Automatically Install apps after factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/automatically-install-apps-after-factory-reset?lq=1)
- [How to recover apps from a factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/how-to-recover-apps-from-a-factory-reset)

Comment: I don't want to recover/reinstall the apps after a factory rest from backup or google play store.

Comment: then you can write your own app that can install the other one.

Comment: Then you would have to install this Meta Installer App: --> Same Problem